# MySQL - Friends Leaderboard ranking by wins and include player in ranking

Tags: php, mysql, leaderboard

**Platform:** MySQL/PHP

**Scenario:** Create Friend Leaderboard which includes all friends of a player and also include the player in the leaderboard within a single query.

**Details:** I'm trying to create a query where the results include the player selected along with all their friends. Ranking will be determined on who has the greatest number of wins.

**Question:** Can this be done within a single query or is it faster to get the result set then compare each friend # of wins to the player # of wins to determine rank order.

**Other Details:**

Here is the query I have to return a player and their friends along with wins and money total:

```
SELECT a.profile_id, 'player', a.win AS player_wins, b1.profile_id AS friend_id,
b1.handle AS friend_handle, b1.win AS friend_wins, b1.bankroll AS friend_bank
FROM ldrbrd_cache_tmp a, buddy_tbl b, ldrbrd_cache_tmp b1
WHERE a.profile_id = b.profile_id
AND b.buddy_id = b1.profile_id
AND a.profile_id <> 1
AND b.buddy_id <> 1
AND a.profile_id = 2
ORDER BY a.profile_id, b1.win DESC;
```

Results:

```
id | name   | player-wins | friend-id | friend-name | friend-wins | friend-money

'2','player'   ,'200'       ,'50'      ,'Freddy K'    ,'303'       ,'10004572'
'2','player'   ,'200'       ,'53'      ,'dannn'       ,'217'       ,'92065'
'2','player'   ,'200'       ,'51'      ,'YoDood'      ,'126'       ,'2383600'
'2','player'   ,'200'       ,'58'      ,'princess'    ,'19'        ,'89565'
'2','player'   ,'200'       ,'71'      ,'com-on'      ,'8'         ,'-9530'
'2','player'   ,'200'       ,'57'      ,'foolzzz'     ,'7'         ,'210'`
```

The results show the player-wins being 200 so in this case the player should be ranked #3.

You will notice I have the player wins but how can I compare the player wins along with the friend wins to return ranking within the same SQL statement? OR is the best course of action to just assign results to an array then determine where the player fits?

**EDIT:** 
So I came up with a UNION that works, is this the only option??

```
SELECT profile_id, handle, win FROM (
SELECT a.profile_id, a.handle, a.win
FROM ldrbrd_cache_tmp a
WHERE a.profile_id = 2
UNION ALL SELECT b1.profile_id, b1.handle, b1.win
FROM ldrbrd_cache_tmp a, buddy_tbl b, ldrbrd_cache_tmp b1
WHERE a.profile_id = b.profile_id
AND b.buddy_id = b1.profile_id
AND a.profile_id <> 1
AND b.buddy_id <> 1
AND a.profile_id = 2
ORDER BY profile_id, win DESC) AS player_ranking
ORDER BY win DESC;
```

This seems to work for now, unless someone has a better solution?